# C++ (14) and manual memory management

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++14

I have just received a comment, like

> The problem is the manual memory management. `delete` has no place in user code, and as of C++14, nor has `new`

Can someone please explain me why?

Comment: While there is a grain of truth in it, as it stands, the statement is outright wrong, so don't ask for an explanation. It is as wrong as "macros have no place in programs" and "templates cause bloat" or as any absolute dogma of that kind. Dogma, no matter what is stupid, it only tells you about the limited mindset of the zealots pursuing it.

Comment: @Damon I'm not the author of that statement, but completely agree with it. Do you have any example that comes up in user code where `delete` or `new` is the optimal choice?

Comment: @Damon Could you explain **why** it is “outright wrong”?

Comment: @stefan: There is nothing inherently wrong with `make_shared` nor with `make_unique` (that's what C++14 will call it?), nor with `new` and `delete`, apart from requiring a little care. Sure, you can use a `shared_ptr` everywhere and never waste a thought again, but there is no compelling reason that you should have to. You can get away with unique pointers in some places, which have no overhead. At times, though, these are just not good enough, but you also don't need the guarantees given by `shared_ptr`, nor the overhead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's wrong because it's one of those dogmatic blanket statements. Even if it applies well for the vast majority of cases (which I'm not doubting), "has no place" is still simply wrong.

Comment: @Damon So use a custom smart pointer or other RAII mechanism in this case. Don’t clutter the user code with memory management. That makes it error-prone and violates SRP. And it’s a “blanket statement” in the same sense as SRP is. That doesn’t make it wrong.

Comment: @Damon I keep hearing you saying the same thing again. Please, show me a typical _user_-code (i.e. not trying to write a smart_ptr) in which a raw pointer is preferable to unique_ptr.

Comment: I've written code that acquires in c'tors and releases in d'tors using pointers for two decades. And I claim with certainity that I've never had a memory leak or a dereference that went wrong because of using a raw pointer there. Don't get me wrong, I **certainly** had these, but because I forgot to initialize an object or forgot to remove it from a container somewhere, or the like. Never because of a raw pointer in a class that wasn't properly deleted from the destructor or such. While smart pointers are helpful, a blanket statement that there is no other valid way is simply a lie.

Comment: Seeing the reasoning and how the comments have gone this is really opinion based, I don't really see a constructive conversation going on here.

Comment: @Damon Well if you use `unique_ptr` you don't even have to write destructors anymore (in most cases). Two decades may sound impressive (and I cannot compete with that, as I'm just 24 years old), but it doesn't mean that there isn't a better way _now_. While _you_ may be very good at covering all places where you need to `delete`, most users tend to forget it and make a mess.

Comment: This is the same story as people saying that using C style arrays are the devil, and you should always use `std::vector`. Yes, for 95% of the cases, that is a good guideline, but as a blanket statement this is just wrong. There are valid situations where `vector` simply doesn't cut it and does the exact the opposite of what you want, and where an unsafe C array on the stack is perfectly safe and a hundred times better. (This has been relativated by the advent of `std::array` -- now if C++14 provides for VLA too, there's really very little reason left)

Comment: @Voo: A class acquiring in the constructor and releasing in the destructor **is** a RAII solution. The fact that these haven't failed me in 2 decades certainly is a good argument. You only need to admit that a smart pointer is nothing different and nothing special, except the smart pointer does nothing else. Which may be OK for many (even the majority of) cases, but "nothing else works" is simply wrong. You can abstract everything away, but then you educate programmers into no longer thinking. Programming is about solving problems, not about applying dogma.

Comment: @Damon C++1y has `std::dynarray`, which is basically a VLA. I don't think they plan on having C VLAs though

Comment: @Damon "And I claim with certainity that I've never had a memory leak or a dereference that went wrong because of using a raw pointer there." -- has any code you have written been modified by others and had a memory leak or invalid pointer dereference? You must have a high control over who touches your code. Writing code is easy: maintainable code is hard. `std::vector` isn't a generic C style array: it is a dynamic resizable array.  `std::dynarray` is a replacement for a C style dynamic array. Finally, does your `new`/`delete` code handle exceptions being thrown by any of the `new`s?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> **Caveat**: I stand by this answer since I think it presents a best practice which will improve ~95% of C++ code – probably even more. That said, please read the *full* comments for a discussion of some important caveats.

Since it was my comment, here’s [my presentation](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp) explaining this.

In a nutshell:

> **[Raw] pointers
>   must. not. own.
>   resources.**

It’s error-prone and unnecessary because we have better ways of managing resources which result in less errors, shorter, more readable code and higher *confidence* in the correctness of the code. In economic terms: they cost less.

To be more specific with regards to the comment I made:

As of C++11 (out now for two years and implemented, in the relevant parts, by all modern compilers), manually deleting memory is completely unnecessary (unless you write **very** low-level memory handling code) because you can always use smart pointers instead, and usually don’t even need them (see the presentation). However, C++11 still requires you to use `new` when instantiating a new `std::unique_ptr`. In C++14, the function [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) makes this usage of `new` unnecessary. Consequently, it’s not needed any more either.

There is still arguably a place for placement-`new` in code, but this is (a) an entirely different case from normal `new`, even though the syntax is similar, and (b) can be replaced in most cases by using the [`allocator::construct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct) function.

---

James has pointed out an exception to this rule which I had honestly forgotten about: when an object manages its own life-time. I’ll go out on a limb and say that this is not a common idiom in most scenarios, because object life-time *can* always be managed externally. However, in certain applications it may be beneficial to decouple the object from the rest of the code and let it manage itself. In that case, you need to dynamically allocate the object and deallocate it using `delete this`.

Comment: @KerrekSB No, I very much include private class members in that statement. I make one exception, and one exception only: when implementing your own smart pointer. Everything else would fail my code review.

Comment: Beautiful slides! (though I tortured my mouse quite a while until I used my keyboard to advance)

Comment: @stefan Ah, sorry for that. I always wanted to include instructions on the first slide, never found the time …

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I don't know ... inside your own data structure, like a tree or graph or something like that, raw pointers can be appropriate, because the ownership semantics are part of the class invariant that the author has under control.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Or, for a simpler example, `std::vector`. It has no need nor place for smart pointers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Excellent presentation! Thanks for sharing it :) However: What is your advice for real life situations, like inheriting a project which has (working) manual memory management. Would you continue *their* style or impose the smart pointer way? And what if your compiler has no support for the latest and shiniest C++ features? And your company does not want to upgrade due to policies?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Raw pointers shouldn't own resources is a bit of a pleonasm, since pointers cannot own resources.  Most pointers in a well written C++ program (starting with `this`) will be raw pointers.  And the most frequent reason for using dynamic allocation (the need for arbitrary object lifetime) precludes the use of smart pointers.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don’t understand that statement. For instance, the three or graph can be modelled just fine with (Boost) containers or unique/shared smart pointers. Raw pointers are fine as long as they don’t own memory. Memory ownership *should* be encoded in the type system – by using an appropriate smart pointer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The slides really don't show any of the cases where you would want to use dynamic allocation, so are rather irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Anyhow, insisting on using smart pointers everywhere is a major anti-pattern.

Comment: @James The slides show *tons* of cases where dynamic allocation is routinely used. The slides, while making no claim of completeness, easily cover 99% of the use cases for `new` in typical code. Beyond the slides, however, I *do* make the claim for completeness (see comments above). And why don’t you give an argument why insistence on smart pointers is an anti-pattern? (But note that I don’t insist on that at all, rather, I insist on automatic resource management – this is far more general than smart pointers, which I personally use rarely).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Especially at the start, yes.  The slides show cases where dynamic allocation is misused.  I agree with these, but curiously, I've yet to see anyone working in industry who would have used dynamic allocation in those cases.  In many applications, the major (and sometimes the only) use of dynamic allocation is for entity objects, whose lifetime is determined by external events, and so cannot be managed by smart pointers (at least not any I've seen).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Using smart pointers where appropriate is not an anti-pattern.  The anti-pattern is trying to use them everywhere you're using dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Konrad: I think I've discussed this kind of thing before with James. He seems to me to program primarily in a style that I don't think is really the norm (not intended as a criticism). In this style entity objects often (always?) are not "owned" by other entities in the sense that smart pointers and containers encapsulate. It's a little like writing a state machine in place of structured flow of control. It's a property of the structure of the program that entities are destroyed at the correct time, not directly attributed to a particular owner (or even group of shared owners) releasing them.

Comment: I don't program primarily in that style, but I use it often enough that I came to write nearly the same comment as James, just to see that he already made it. (And knowing James, I wonder how much he doesn't exaggerate his use of the style to make his point clearer).

Comment: @SteveJessop Rather than a "style": maybe it's a function of the application domains.  Smart pointers don't work for most entity objects in a server, for example, since the decision as to when the object must be deleted will be the result of a client request.  And they don't work with complex graphs, which may contain cycles.  (And of course, you'd never use them in the real-time applications I worked on many years ago; deterministic latency means _no_ dynamic allocation.)

Comment: @James I very much agree with your anti-pattern comment concerning the over-use of smart pointers. I’d like to point out that I’ve never advocated this, on the contrary. `std::shared_ptr` in particular tends to be over-used.

Comment: @AProgrammer There's some exaggeration, but mainly simply to insist that the "silver bullet" of smart pointers isn't one.  (FWIW: the application I currently work on does use shared pointers almost everywhere.  But I've worked on enough different applications to realize that it isn't typical.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: the reason I see it as a style is that other people would fit the entities into some kind of collection. Which no doubt could be criticised as a God object responsible for a process of continuous maintenance of the universe. That is to say, the "obviously correct" solution to you is a matter of choice for someone else who doesn't see it as obvious. But maybe I over-use the word "style", basically I use it almost whenever there's a choice between two correct programs.

Comment: @KonradRudolph But when you start by saying "f*ck pointers", you give the wrong impression.  I'm not against smart pointers (I think I'm actually one of the inventors of them), but I am against their being presented as a silver bullet, which is almost always the case.  They're useful in specific cases, but in other (relatively frequent) cases, trying to use them will only be a source of additional errors.

Comment: @SteveJessop The entities _must_ be in some sort of collections (something like a map, usually), since you have to be able to find them.  But you don't really mean to say that to delete the object, you remove it from the map, do you?  I've always seen the reverse: the destructor of the object removes it from the map.

Comment: @James The slides are intentionally inflammatory. They are *presentation slides* for chrissake, that’s their job. The reason being, most C++ (even seasoned) programmers have a woeful over-reliance on manual memory management, which is driving me absolutely crazy because it impacts code quality so substantially.

Comment: @JamesKanze: yes, they have to be reachable via whatever routes entities interact. I've never looked at any sizeable amount of code by you, but the impression I've had from our discussion is that you were talking about cases where other programmers would make the collection responsible for ownership, so that yes, expiring the object becomes an operation on the collection(-holder) rather than an operation on the entity. But sorry, I don't intend to speak for you, I just thought Konrad might be seeing things from a POV I recognized and I could speed through some of that discussion.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think that's where we disagree.  I simply don't see it in the programmers I've worked with over the last 20 or some years.  For example, I don't think I've ever seen `int* p = new int;` in actual code, _except_ in places like this, where people are trying to learn C++ coming from Java.  (Or maybe...  There was one special case where a virtual function returned a `std::string const&`.  Given a compiler warning about returning a reference to a temporary, one programmer ended up with `return *new std::string(...);`.  But those are exceptions.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I was referring to the implementation of `vector`: The container certainly owns its memory and its element objects, but I see nothing wrong with it using private raw pointers to track that state. Another example is a tree structure with a parent pointer, which you'd like to be null for the root. They're non-owning pointers, but any other solution that avoids raw pointers would be clunkier and more awkward.

Comment: @KerrekSB I do. It violates SRP. I’d implement `vector` via `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` and I feel that this should be the canonical way of implementing it. See also Martinho’s influential [Rule of Zero article](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html). And as I’ve said before, non-owning raw pointers are fine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I'm pretty sure you can't if you want to have preallocation handled correctly.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Agreed. Standard containers present a tricksy case I think, because the deleter of a smart pointer would have to access the vector's allocator object. But it's a long time since I implemented a container, and that was as an exercise. I may be missing some obvious way that it can be done correctly and efficiently with `unique_ptr`, where "efficiently" should probably mean "not embedding a pointer to the vector in a data member of the vector". Maybe one could argue that it's only because it's library code (not "user code") that we'd have such high standards, but that's a stretch.

Comment: @JamesKanze It’s a known fact that many big products had these problems. Firefox and OpenOffice.org (or at least its predecessors) are two examples.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That wouldn't work.  In fact, you cannot use any of the classic smart pointers in `vector`, because none support the required separation of allocation and initialization.  (On the other hand, you do need something, unless you want a lot of `try` blocks.  The canonical implementation, I think, puts the three internal pointers in a separate object type, which will take care of proper clean-up.)

Comment: @AProgrammer True. In that case you would use allocators anyway. I’d wrap that into a smart pointer anyway. Again, the reason is SRP and rule of zero. It’s simply less error-prone to do it this way unthinkingly, rather than spending time to ensure resources are handled correctly.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I think there are much easier things to consider: For example 1, a vector separates memory from storage, so it needs pointers to track the memory, and placement-new to construct objects. That's a perfectly fine solution and raw pointers serve just fine. For example 2, please reconsider my "tree" example: How do you store a pointer to the parent node better than with a raw pointer?

Comment: @KerrekSB: the pointer from a node to its parent is non-owning, so does not stand as counter-example to anything Konrad has said. In the case of `vector` I imagine an elaborate deleter. It would consult the vector for the size, so it knows how many elements to destroy, and the allocator to destroy the objects and free the block. Or maybe the destructor of the container could resize to 0 so that the smart pointer only has to worry about the block, not the elements. Btw standard containers *do not* use placement new, they use `construct` on the allocator. Granted it raises the same issue ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Ah, yes, I see now that Konrad has a slightly different approach. Personally, I use "do not use public raw pointers" as a maxim, which seems to be a little broader yet still applicable.

Comment: @KerrekSB, even non owning one?

Comment: Another way to look at this, which does cover `vector` and that Konrad has mentioned in context of SRP, is that anything which uses a raw pointer for ownership is *by definition* a custom smart pointer (regardless of whether it has the usual `operator->` etc, that's just a matter of how custom you want it to be). So the design question is do you want `vector` to be a smart pointer, or do you want to write a smart pointer for `vector`'s use, that separates allocation from initialization as necessary? Normally the latter, and only some possible optimization would justify the former.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes.  I'd agree with this with regards to vector, for example.  There's definitely a smart something involved; it's a bit more than just a pointer (since it maintains at the least the pointer and something to indicate how far things have been constructed), but there's a real sense in which the concept is the same.

Comment: @SteveJessop, a smart pointer is usually responsible to destroy the object and free the memory under the correct circumstance for the policy it implements.  I'm not sure I'd make the helper class for a std::vector responsible for both and that make me more uneasy with calling it a smart pointer than an absence of operator->.

Comment: @AProgrammer: Yeah - publicly, you shouldn't need non-owning raw pointers; there's usually always a better solution. I mean, it's not an absolute rule, but it's a good start.

Comment: @KerrekSB, references are not rebindable so the alternative is that you have a weak pointer for every smart pointer you use?

Comment: @AProgrammer: I'm not saying there's a drop-in replacement for every line of code that currently contains raw pointers; rather, there's a *style* of programming that should avoid them most times.

Answer (score 3):

`Smart pointers` and in turn `std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique` should be used instead because dealing with `new/delete` etc. is more prone to errors when applications throw exceptions etc.

Smart pointers automatically delete(utilising [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)) when used even when exceptions are thrown unlike new/delete which can leak memory

See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for more info

Comment: Exceptions are a totally overused trope. That's not the real reason at all. It's much more important that unique pointers use the type system to force you to know at all times who is responsible for a resource, and make it impossible to forget to clean up. To wit, the expression `new T;` is a bug; the expression `make_unique<T>();` is not.

Comment: This is, of course, completely wrong.  The most frequent reason for using dynamic memory in user code, in fact, precludes using smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing the quoted statement says is that the person
who said it doesn't really understand program design or the way
C++ works (and the way dynamic memory is used in C++).  The
statement defines an anti-pattern, more than anything else.

There *are* particular types of applications where it might be
applicable; the application I work on currently is one.  But
it's not general, and in most of the applications I've worked on
in the past, most of the deletes have been in user code.  (Those
that weren't were in basic classes like `std::vector`.)

Comment: James, you should know better. And your reply lacks any approximation of an argument. It merely shows that most of the code you’ve worked on the past was typical C++ code. – I.e. not very robust.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I do know better.  I've worked (and written from scratch) a number of C++ applications over more than 20 years.  The only one that leaked resources is when I tried to follow the rule of using smart pointers for everything.  (There were, inevitably, cycles.)  There are times when smart pointers are appropriate, but it's not a general rule.  (In a lot of applications, most `delete` will be `delete this`, for example.)

Comment: Given my (and other people’s) experience with C++ applications, I *seriously* doubt your claim (at the very least it would be highly atypical for the industry). Rather, I posit that this was the only application where you *noticed* the memory leaks. That said, thanks for the `delete this` example. It’s a sufficiently arcane case that I forgot about it, but when you’re working in asynchronous systems it probably occurs regularly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Most of the applications I wrote in the past were large scale servers (mostly telephone routing systems), which ran 24 hours a day, 7 days a week, for years at a time, with conventional penalties for down-time (10 thousand DM a minute, in one case).  The proof of the pudding is in the eating, as they say.  I feel safe in saying that those applications didn't leak memory.  (FWIW: the applications did use my pre-standard shared pointers in a few specific cases.  But only in specific cases.)