# Should I write "delete" at the end of a program

Tags: object, delete-operator

Should I write "delete" at the end of a program? I know that all existing object at the end of a program are destroyed anyway, so is it a good or bad habit to delete them?

Comment: Yes you should write, and no, you don´t know that they "are destroyed anyway" because that´s nonsense. The behaviour of some OS is not everything in the world. edit: Resource != local memory. Some OS can free the memory, but what´s about files, sockets etc. etc.? Yes, even today, the automatic stuff of the OS does not handle all situations perfectly.

Comment: [You shouldn’t write `delete` anywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22250859/1968)