# C++: Access Violation when reading pointer captured by Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I am not gonna pretend I am very experienced with lambdas, but with this seemingly simple issue, I think I need deeper insight on how it actually works.

I am instantiating an object on an outer scope, and using 2 lambdas, I attempt to modify that pointer.

```
// Object to be manipulated
Object* obj= nullptr;

// To be invoked externally in order to construct and initialize obj
std::function<void(std::function<void(const String&)>)> SetObject
    = [&obj](std::function<void(const String&)> func) 
{
    obj= new Object();
    // ... Initialize Values
};

// To be invoked externally to reset and delete obj
std::function<void()> ResetObject
= [&obj]() 
{
    if(obj)
    {
        delete obj;
        obj= nullptr;
    }
};
```

A main code executes and first calls the **RESET** method before creating a new instance of Object. Assume the "main" code has no way of accessing, reading, or modifying obj - hence the reliance on a blind reset.

**Expected Result**: The first time the reset expression is invoked, the check on obj should return false because obj was set to nullptr in the outer scope -- nothing happens.

**Actual Result:** By the time reset is executed, obj no longer points to NULL, the check returns true and delete is called, causing an access violation.

I would like to know if the whatever I am attempting to do is an invalid operation to begin with, or whether the way I am capturing my variables is incorrect. I tried capturing the pointer by value, setting the function to mutable, and a combination of reference and value capture out of desperation.

> **EDIT:** At this point, I believe the scope of the object is the main culprit as pointed out by others. I will attempt a workaround with
>   that in mind and report back.

Comment: Did `obj` go out of scope when the lambda's are called?

Comment: Yeah, we really need to know the scope of that declaration. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make this obvious.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to strip it down as much as I could because I was not allowed to share the context of this code. I can say that the code I showed (alongside many other lambda expressions) are within a Initialization function that gets called when the application first runs. Please feel free to delete the question if that is not enough information.

Comment: Is there a good reason that you can't wrap `obj` instead a smart pointer, i.e. `std::unique_ptr<Object>`?

Comment: @Xirema I think it defeats the purpose of providing the means to explicitly create and delete that object and hence manage the lifetime of the object. Nonetheless I did try using a unique_ptr but a similar error was thrown.

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to hint at is that [you should avoid manual resource management as much as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250859/c-14-and-manual-memory-management), and smart pointers are the usual mechanism for achieving that. Manually and explicitly managing the lifetime of a resource *is not something you should desire*. In the best-case scenario, it's a necessary evil, and in the worst-case scenario, it's the engine for all your bugs and mishaps (like, for example, the access violation you're getting in your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we cannot tell from your example alone, I suspect `obj` is perhaps a local variable which goes out of scope after being captured. One way to solve this would be to add another level of indirection:

```
Object** objptr = new Object*();

std::function<void(std::function<void(const String&)>)> SetObject
    = [objptr](std::function<void(const String&)> func) 
{
    *objptr = new Object();
};

std::function<void()> ResetObject
= [objptr]() // Note we are now capturing objptr by value
{
    if(*objptr)
    {
        delete *objptr;
        *objptr = nullptr;
    }
    // Is objptr reused by another call to SetObject?
    // If not, delete it here as well.
    // delete objptr;
};
```

Comment: So, is the reason this works is because we captured objptr by VALUE - otherwise, it would fall for the same scoping issue as the original example?